# Getting Date from Unixtimesamp using DateTime not working

Tags: php, datetime, command-line-interface

I have below code, running form command prompt (**CLI**),

```
$date_original  = 1390831200;

try {
 $result             =   new DateTime("@$date_original");
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($result); // prints nothing - i think its null.
```

If I remove `@` in the code I get below error message but not result :

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (**1390831200**)
>   at position 8 (0): Unexpected character

Do not see any php.ini issue.

Just to additional info

from link http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php i was trying to achieve the

Localized Notations

```
Unix Timestamp  "@" "-"? [0-9]+     "@1215282385"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return anything"? I pasted this code to my CLI and it works just fine. It also produces the error just fine if @ is removed. There's nothing wrong with that piece of code.

Comment: @Glavić, is that link output equal to CLI output?, at my windows cli it is having null result.

Comment: @Glavić, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @N.B. i do not see any output seems returning null.

Comment: @Glavić, my mistake, after that code i was doing `var_dump($result);` - which is not  printing anything.

Comment: @codepiper: can you **run [this code](https://eval.in/95382)** in CLI, and then copy/paste here the output?

Comment: `-1-`
`-2-`
`-3-`
`2014-01-27T14:00:00+00:00`
`-4-`
`-6-`

Comment: @Glavić, just want to make sure you get my point, i am trying to get DateTime object from unixtimestamp through CLI. In my case its returning null.

Comment: Long story short, there's nothing wrong with DateTime but with your PHP CLI. Press CTRL + D or CTRL + Z after you enter that code.

Comment: not sure, but below 2 lines working for me  `$date_original1 = new DateTime();`
            `$date_original1->setTimestamp($date_original);`

Comment: @codepiper: I just can't get you... Your example IS working! You already outputted my demo, where you have seen, that your code IS working. And then you say that `->setTimestamp()` is working for you? I am just confused...

Comment: @Glavić, your code also works, it was just i could not understand at that moment, i was thinking in some wrong direction about what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($date_original);
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this:

```
$date_original  = 1390831200;

return date("d.m.Y", $date_original);
```

Comment: Downvote is probably because you're suggesting using standard date functions when the OP is talking about using PHP's DateTime class.... you're suggesting a retrograde step

Comment: Ok, this is just easier.. but things can be done hard way / complex way if really wanted..

Comment: DateTime !== hard/complex; DateTime == Flexible

Comment: Yep, create new class every time you want to format simple datetime.. :) really flexible for example in templates.

Comment: Cleaner ways of working with dates generally, covering a wider range of dates than 32-bit unix timestamps; better handling for period calculations (and easily iterable), proper timezone handling, built-in daylight savings handling, supporting a wider range of string input formats with `createFromFormat()`... yes, a lot more flexible